# Find value of limit $a_n=(1+2^n+3^n+...+n^n)^{1/n}\sin(1/n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+2^n+3^n+...+n^n)^{1/n}\sin(1/n)$. I have tried so far to bound it but I hadn't had any success.

Comment: @Lucian It's $\sum_{k=1}^n k^n$, not $k^k$. So it is $\approx \frac{n^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: ... which, in the end, is still the same as $\approx n^n$, but yes, I got confused. :-$)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n}=n\sin(1/n)\leq a_n\leq (n\cdot n^n)^{1/n}\sin(1/n)=n^{1/n}\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n}$$

Now use that $n^{1/n}\to1$ and $\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n}\to1$.

Comment: It seems this is the answer! Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 5):

For all $n$
$$
n^n<1+2^n+3^n+...+n^n<n\,n^n.
$$
Taking the $n$-th root
$$
n<(1+2^n+3^n+...+n^n)^{1/n}<n^{1/n}\,n.
$$
Can you follow from here?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the sum to the integral $\int_{1}^{n} x^n dx$, rewrite the expression as $x= e^{\log x}$ and use Maclaurin series for sine: $e^{\log \sin x} \sim e^{\log (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^3} +O(\frac{1}{n^5}))} = \frac{1}{n} +\frac{1}{n^3} +O(\frac{1}{n^5})$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} 
(1+2^n+3^n+\cdots+n^n)^{1/n}\sin(1/n) = \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} 
(1+2^n+3^n+\cdots+n^n)^{1/n} (1/n) \cdot \overbrace{\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n}}^1 =\\
\frac 1n (1+2^n+3^n+\cdots+n^n)^{1/n} = \\
((1/n)^n+(2/n)^n+(3/n)^n+\cdots+1^n)^{1/n}
$$
We can then treat $(1/n)^n+(2/n)^n+(3/n)^n+\cdots+1^n$ as the Riemann sum of a certain integral.